# How can I grep nth column of tab delimited file in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, grep, csv

My source file is tab delimited and I need to grep the 4th column of values. How can I do this in Groovy? Here's my code which doesn't work. Is it even close?

```
 def tab_file = new File('source_file.tab')
 tab_file.eachline { line -> println line.grep('\t\t\t\t'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split by tab character, that would give you an array you can index into to get the column:

```
groovy:000> s = "aaa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\teee";
===> aaa        bbb     ccc     ddd     eee
groovy:000> s.split("\\t")[3]
===> ddd
```

Comment: Don't forget about multiple assignment `def (name, age, city) = "john\t18\tnew york".split("\t");` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
tab_file.eachLine { line -> 
    println ((line =~ /([^\t]*\t){3}([^\t]*)/)[0][2])
}
```

**Explanation:**
The `=~` operator creates a `java.util.regex.Matcher` object using the pattern on the right-hand side.  Groovy lets you then implicitly execute `find()` via the array subscript operator.  If your regex has groups in it, this results in a `List` for each result.  This list has the whole matched area as element 0, then the groups as further elements.  So `[0][2]` is the first match of the regex (zero-indexed), specifically the 2nd group match.  (Btw, if there were no groups in the regex, the result is just a string with the match).  Details/Examples [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions).

**Update/Aside:**
I was just looking into the `grep()` fxnality added to [Object](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#grep%28java.lang.Object%29), as I was curious.  I'm not sure I see the utility outside of collection types, but when applied to Strings, it doesn't do as you might expect - it appears to loop through the characters in the string, and compares each character against the passed-in String (collecting matches in a list).  If your passed-in String is >1 character, you'll never get a match, as the character under inspection per iteration will never equal the whole string passed-in (in your example, any `\t != "\t\t\t\t"`)

Comment: Brian, when I try your code I get a MissingMethodException: No signature of method java.io.file.eachline() message...

Comment: sorry, i copied it from the original post.  fixed now.

Comment: added info on [0][2] to body of answer